# Did I correctly find the X value for this tangent function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, special-functions

**EDIT: Can someone show me how to do these questions? Feel like I haven't done it correctly**

So I am going of an earlier post that someone did on the forum, its pretty similar so I must have ended up getting the same textbook, but anyways, just posting it here to check if I worked everything out correctly (no answers are given).

The textbook asks to find the $x$ value "at which f(x) is undefined".

*Question 1:* $f(x)=-5tan(3.4x+7.1)+0.6$

**My working was this basically how the other question put it:**

**calculated the equation** $3.4x+7.1=\frac{\pi}{2}$ **and I got $-1.6262$**

*Question 2:* $f(x)=7.3tan(5.6x)+3.0$

**My working was exactly the same:** $5.6x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ **and I got $0.28050$**

Did I get both correct? Just to restate, the section was asking for "the value of x at which f(x) is undefined".

If I didn't get them correct, could someone correct them?

Comment: $\tan t$ is undefined at many more $t$s, for example $\frac{-\pi}2$, $\frac{3\pi}2$, $\frac{-3\pi}2$, $\frac{5\pi}2$, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @peterwhy pointed out, the function $\tan(\theta)$ is undefined at an infinite number of values, specifically any $\theta=(2n-1)\frac\pi 2, n\in \mathbb Z $. Using this fact you can now solve your equations for $x$.

---

(1) $f(x)=−5tan(3.4x+7.1)+0.6$

We solve $3.4x+7.1=(2n-1)\frac\pi 2$ to get the general solution as $$x=\frac{(2n-1)\frac\pi 2-7.1}{3.4},n\in\mathbb Z$$

(2) $f(x)=7.3tan(5.6x)+3.0$

Similarly solving $5.6x=(2m-1)\frac\pi 2$ yields
$$x=\frac{(2m-1)\frac\pi 2}{5.6},m\in \mathbb Z$$

---

Also note that inputting $n=1$ and $m=1$ in the respective equations gives the solutions you calculated.